# seq method unexpected value

Tags: r

Unexpectedly for the command:

```
seq(-0.30,0.60,0.10)
```

i receive the answer:

```
 [1] -3.000000e-01 -2.000000e-01 -1.000000e-01  5.551115e-17  1.000000e-01  2.000000e-01  3.000000e-01  4.000000e-01  5.000000e-01
[10]  6.000000e-01
```

Note the non zero value in 4th element,
whereas for the command:

```
seq(-0.40,0.60,0.10)
```

The return result is (as expected):

```
 [1] -0.4 -0.3 -0.2 -0.1  0.0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6
```

I suppose this is a round problem. 
The issue here is that I am using the seq command for creating a legend and therefore my legend becomes badly formatted. 
Apart from the obvious replacement of the value or the construction of a `c()` command, did anyone else get this error? Is this a bug?

I am using Rstudio Version 1.0.136 and R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31).

Comment: It is not a bug. Just round the result or use `pretty()`.

Comment: I think it is the same issue as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, that's just [precision and floating point numbers](http://blog.reverberate.org/2014/09/what-every-computer-programmer-should.html)...

It's usually easier to do:

```
seq(-3,6) / 10
```

which gives:

```
-0.3 -0.2 -0.1  0.0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6
```

Comment: Or just `-3:6/10`

Comment: Instead of "*easier*" I would say "*safer*" as `seq(-3,6)` returns an integer vector. I would also argue it's safer to do `10L` instead of `10` in order to make sure we are not dividing by a float.